# String matching in RStudio

Tags: r, string

I am having trouble with the following scenario. I have a dataframe `df` that has multi-word strings in `var1`.  I want to keep only the words from `var1` if that word is in `chr`. For example, the first row of `var1` has "car tv dog" and I want to delete the word "dog" because it is not in `chr`.

My dataframe:

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
var1 <- c("car tv dog","cat water mouse","pen wire fish")
df <- data.frame(id,var1)
```

Words I want to keep:

```
chr<-"car aaa bbb ccc ddd qqq www eee rrr pen cat ttt fish tv"
```

Desired result:

```
want <- c("car tv","cat","pen fish")
dfWant <- data.frame(id, var1, want)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to create the second data frame. What's the pattern? Also, what's `chr` doing?

Comment: This is very unclear. Remember that people who read this question are not immersed in the problem like you are. Explain it as if we didn't already know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The want column is the intersection of the string chr and Var1. That is, for the first row, car and tv are present in the string chr while dog is not. Therefore they would be in the want column.

Comment: I'm usually with you @RichScriven, but since he took to commenting instead of editing (and I think the lack of editing was starting to earn him down-votes), I just went ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:3,
    var1 = c("car tv dog", "cat water mouse", "pen wire fish"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# strings to search for (save each word as an element of a vector)
chr <- "car aaa bbb ccc ddd qqq www eee rrr pen cat ttt fish tv"
chr_vec <- unique(unlist(strsplit(chr, " ")))

# split var1 into words, check if word is in chr_vec, 
# keep only if true, re-combine into multi-word string
df$result <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$var1, " "), function(x) paste(x[x %in% chr_vec], collapse = " ")))
```

Result:

```
> df
  id            var1   result
1  1      car tv dog   car tv
2  2 cat water mouse      cat
3  3   pen wire fish pen fish
```